# Making the background move sideways in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to create a game using pygame and I am attempting to add a background to it (I have used some code from a YouTube video but this is not working). I also to not understand what the code is on about. I mean the background and does move but it automatically adds a new version of the background in the middle of the screen when the older background has not gone off screen yet:

```
class Background:
    def __init__(self, x, y, picture):
        self.xpos = x
        self.ypos = y
        self.picture = picture
        self.rect = self.picture.get_rect()
        self.picture = pygame.transform.scale(self.picture, (1280, 720))

    def paste(self, xpos, ypos):
        screen.blit(self.picture, (xpos, ypos))

    def draw(self):
        screen.blit(self.picture, (self.xpos, self.ypos))

while True:

background=pygame.image.load("C:/images/mars.jpg").convert_alpha()       

cliff = Background(0, 0, background)


rel_x = x % cliff.rect.width

cliff.paste(rel_x - cliff.rect.width, 0)
if rel_x < WIDTH:
    cliff.paste(rel_x, 0)
    x -= 1
```

This is what currently happens with my background 
[![what my problem looks like][1]][1]

[![What I want the background to move like ][2]][2]

This is what I want my background to look like (please ignore the sign it was the only one I could find)

I have now discovered what the real problem is

[image: The new problem]

Comment: What do you expect to happen? Do you want the area previously covered by the background to be a single colour? That's easy by adding a `screen.fill(..)` call every loop before you blit your background. Do you want the image to wrap around, that's a little more complex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have a continuously repeating background, then you've to draw the background twice:

[image]

You've to know the size of the screen. The size of the height background image should match the height of the screen. The width of the background can be different, but should be at least the with of the window (else the background has to be drawn more than 2 times).

```py
bg_w, gb_h = size
bg =  pygame.transform.smoothscale(pygame.image.load('background.image'), (bg_w, bg_h))
```

The background can be imagined as a endless row of tiles.
If you want to draw the background at an certain position `pos_x`, then you have to calculate the position of the tile relative to the screen by the modulo (`%`) operator. The position of the 2nd tile is shifted by the width of the background (`bg_w`):

```py
x_rel = pos_x % bg_w
x_part2 = x_rel - bg_w if x_rel > 0 else x_rel + bg_w
```

Finally the background has to be *blit* twice, to fill the entire screen:

```py
screen.blit(bg, (x_rel, 0))
screen.blit(bg, (x_part2, 0))
```

You can test the process by the following example program. The background can be moved by <kbd><-</kbd> respectively <kbd>-></kbd>

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()

size = (800,600)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

bg_w, bg_h = size 
bg = pygame.transform.smoothscale(pygame.image.load('background.image'), (bg_w, bg_h))
pos_x = 0
speed = 10

done = False
while not done:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

    allKeys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    pos_x += speed if allKeys[pygame.K_LEFT] else -speed if allKeys[pygame.K_RIGHT] else 0

    x_rel = pos_x % bg_w
    x_part2 = x_rel - bg_w if x_rel > 0 else x_rel + bg_w

    screen.blit(bg, (x_rel, 0))
    screen.blit(bg, (x_part2, 0))

    pygame.display.flip()
```

Also see [How to make parallax scrolling work properly with a camera that stops at edges pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63712333/how-to-make-parallax-scrolling-work-properly-with-a-camera-that-stops-at-edges-p/74002486#74002486)

Comment: is there a way to make the new background flipped horizontally each time there is a new second background

Answer (score 0):

[This SO answer should have what you need](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/126050/78793)

This seems to provide maybe a smarter and more functional background class than what you're using. I'd say give a try.

Comment: I do not think its to do with my situation

Comment: @Ugandan_Knuckles i am not referencing the comment on it's own. The post had a Background class with all of the apparent functionality of yours. Also, I don't know about your `pygame` but typically (0, 0) is the top left of the screen. Maybe try setting zero at top right? Most bigger image libraries have a way to change zero.

Comment: I have figured out that the background leaves a glitch at the end can you try to please help me with this